# Warcraftlogs: measuring DPS progression over several tries

Tags: world-of-warcraft

As we are currently progressing in Mythic, I find myself a bit down in DPS compared to the rest of my guild. While I already identified some elements, I find some RNG in my rotation heavily impacts the damage output, thus a single parse is not too relevant.

I would like to see my average damage over several part of the fight, on the same time frame, and compare it with a sim to see what I can do better.

Therefore I would like to create a query:

- scoping event to only 2 minutes from the beginning of the fight
- only on the parse that went over 2 minutes
- optionally on parses I didn't die within those 2 minutes.

Is this possible on warcraflogs.com ?

Comment: [It should be possible](https://www.warcraftlogs.com/help/pins) but from personal experience for improving your performance: I'd suggest analyzing some logs with more experienced players of the spec. The class discords are usually very helpful

Comment: "*Is this possible on warcraflogs.com ?*" - Yes. you can create custom queries with those parameters. *But does it help you?* Nope, not really. RNG, proccs, different movement, human error,... there are too many things that can go differently each time you fight that boss. As already stated you're better off asking directly about your class or rotation issues here or on discord or your guild, if you're not able to figure out the problems by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going about it the wrong way. You shouldn't compare yourself to a sim at all because **Sims are not accurate representations of any fight in the game**. Sims are essentially "If I can stand still in a fight for 5 minutes, just chain casting an absolutely perfect rotation into my target without ever stopping to use a defensive, moving to avoid an attack, interrupting a dangerous cast, switching to a different target or using AoE spells, this is the DPS I'll be able to do". That simply is not realistic at all, and the only boss of that type for all players in the raid we've had so far is Patchwerk back in Naxxramas. Sims are literally the perfect fight and unless you're EXTREMELY lucky and never need to do anything extra for any mechanic or special task and NEVER make any mistake compared to perfect play, you're NEVER EVER gonna reach that point.

There are better solutions for this. There is a tool called [Wowanalyzer](https://wowanalyzer.com/), which supports most specs in the game and analyzes your public WoW log parses and determines what you're doing wrong and how to correct it. Now, I can't guarantee that it is fully accurate for your class, but a lot of the advice it gives is generic and as such applies to most encounters, players and classes.

In addition, every WoW class has a dedicated Discord server (you can find these using Google, there are too many to link them all) where expert volunteers for every spec are willing to provide interested players with a personalized analysis of your log, including things Wowanalyzer can't provide suggestions for like positioning and specialized tactics for dealing with specific mechanics, like using unique utility abilities and talents to completely trivialize certain boss mechanics.